# Problem with openssl (can't connect to gmail)

Tags: openssl, smtp

I'm trying to use openssl (windows platform) to remote access my gmail and send a sample email to any other arbitrary email address. I'm reading the manual from the https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/server/testing/smtp/ but i am even stuck in the first step. When trying to execute the command

**OpenSSL> s_client -starttls smtp -connect gmail.com:25**

I encounter an error as following

**OpenSSL> s_client -starttls smtp -connect gmail.com:25
4792:error:0200274C:system library:connect:reason(1868):crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:110:
4792:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0
error in s_client**

Also I get a similar error when trying to connect on port # 465,587. Would you please help me with?

Comment: Links, images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of or links to examples, code, data, or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/data/message into the post directly. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How does it look? Do you also have any solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to the correct subdomain,

- `smtp.gmail.com` port 25
- `smtp.gmail.com` port 465
- `smtp.gmail.com` port 587

Here is a full example of a working connection.

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:25
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = smtp.gmail.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = smtp.gmail.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
   i:OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = smtp.gmail.com

issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3035 bytes and written 429 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 SMTPUTF8
```